# How to get push notification in background without tappin on the notification in ios?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have googled, but not getting the answer.

Please let me know how to get the push notification in the background state of the app, and update the same in the background, without knowing to user.

I have played with the capabilities, didReceiveRemoteNotification but all is vain.

I am using the FCM for the same.

Please help me...

Comment: this is not possible and never will be

Comment: You can use silent notification

Comment: no, app don't know about notification, system gives the information when user interacts with it. Maybe something with jailbreak would help

Comment: You have to set "content-available:1" in payload and you have to enable background fetch in capabilites

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To receive push notification in background state and be able to update your app data you need to setup few things in your project :

1. Enable "Remote notification" capability in Project settings > Capabilities > Background Modes.
2. In the payload that you send to APNS, add the flag "content-avalaible" = 1. This will tell your app that this Push notification intimates the app that it needs to get new data.
3. Now to handle these notifications with "content-avalaible", the system will invoke your AppDelegate method `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` and **NOT** `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:`
4. You have to put your data refresh logic in this method. Acc to documentation you need to perform your data refresh within 30 seconds ideally. Also you need to call the `completionHandler` with correct value of `UIBackgroundFetchResult`. There are 3 values, please read what relates to what.

Having known all this, I should also highlight that delivering push notification to your app is entirely system's wish which depends upon :

- How often you keep sending the push. This shouldn't be more than 4 Push per minute ideally.
- When the app is invoked, what is the CPU processing and battery consumption involved.
- And also how many times was your Push invocation responded with actual Data refresh. Thats what the `completionHandler` is for.
- Note there are bugs in iOS 11 which are deferring the app invocation.
- **IMPORTANT** : The app will not be invoked to refresh data on Push notification if the user has killed the app. Once the app is killed, the Push can only invoke the app, ONLY if user opens the app again and keeps it in background OR he restarts his device.

Hope all this should help you setup and test.